# How to ensure an execution of onResponse in the same order as it has been requested?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I've a recyclerview in which I call a rest service in a onBindViewHolder function, so it's called when the rows that fit on screen or the recyclerview is scrolled to certain rows.

I'm doing it via retrofit like this:

```
Call<FotografiasGeoBean> call = restClient.getData(allNeededParams);
```

Point is that I'd like to save the recyclerview values, so if I go to another activity by pressing the recyclerview row and then I go back, it's not neccesary to make all calls again.

It looks like I've the code to do that except for the problem that I cannot ensure that the values are received in the same order they were requested, for example if I make the petition for the row 0 on the recyclerview and then the petition for row 1, I may get the answer for row 1 before the one for row 0, then if I save the value in an ArrayList, it's incorrect.

Which way could I ensure a proper execution so the values saved in the ArrayList always match with the ones from the position of the row in the RecyclerView?

Comment: Your request and response handler should know/contain row number. It should not matter which response comes first.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want is a good way to save data but  for what you want it's better to use a `HashMap` instead of an `Arraylist` in this way you can put values with their position and retrieve them, regardless of the order of adding .

```
  HashMap<Integer, YourDataClass> hashMap= new HashMap<>();
  hashMap.put(1,yourData1)
  hashMap.put(0,yourDatat2)
  // and you can retrieve data like this in any order you want
  hashMap.get(1) // returns value at position 1
  hashMap.get(0) // returns value at position 0
```

and for finding position in ViewHolder you can use `getAdapterPosition()` method